# How to get typed response object in IActionFilter. ASP Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In controller action I return typed c# object:

```
public async Task<DTO.CartResponse> IndexAsync()
        {
         ...   
            DTO.CartProduct[] productsResponse = await _requestsRouter.Send(req);
            return new DTO.CartResponse() { items = productsResponse} ;           
        }
```

How to get DTO.CartResponse in IActionFilter?

```
  public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
             DTO.CartResponse response = ?
        }
```

Some SO answers suggest using `actionExecutedContext.Response.TryGetContentValue` but I do not have this in my context.HttpContext.Response.
Also no Content object:
[image]

Comment: Maybe do some learning by using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to see what is actually returned.  Every server will return different response.  The response will depend on the properties (headers) in the request and the data in the database.

Comment: @jdweng my question is about getting response object in asp core 2.2 Filter. ASP core filters: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: The MSDN example are only sample code and the response will be different depending on the Server you are using.  You have to modify the sample code depending on the response you are getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to get DTO.CartResponse in IActionFilter?

Please refer to the following code snippet:

```
public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
{
    if (context.Result.GetType().Equals(typeof(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult)))
    {
        var res = ((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult)context.Result).Value;

        if (res.GetType().Equals(typeof(CartResponse)))
        {
            CartResponse response = res as CartResponse;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[ActionExecutedContext documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh835782(v%3Dvs.118)) mentions the Resonse property which is of type [HttpResponseMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8).

So you can access the `HttpContent` by

```
    context.Response.Content
```

An example would be the following:

```
var content = context.Response.Content;
if (content != null) {
       var value = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; //holding the returned value
}
```

Or try with

```
var content = context.Response.Content as ObjectContent;
if (content != null) {
       var value = content.value; //holding the returned value
}
```

Comment: I do not have context.Response.Content. I have context.HttpContext.Response which does not have ReadAsStringAsync() method.

Comment: Try with the second option. I've seen it somewhere, but I'm not sure it works. Let me know

Comment: Please also let me know the type of the Content object. Let me know by hovering on it during debugging, so that I can help you more.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following, to get the result.

```
context.Result
```

Comment: Probably this is it since Result is type of IAction result.Could you post full code?